# Человеческий — людской?

Tags: значение-слов

Какова разница в смысле между словами *человеческий* и *людской?* Можно было бы предположить, что *людской* относится к человечеству в целом, но мы помним, что комната для прислуги в русском доме называлась людской.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю,что полные синонимы встречаются редко, обычно имеются небольшие различия в оттенках значений, а также в сочетаемости с разными словами. В частности, это касается и слов "человеческий - людской".

Вряд ли можно сказать "людской организм", не очень хорошо звучит (хотя встречается) "людское достоинство". Да и вообще, было бы странным не разделять признаки, отнесенные, с одной стороны, к индивидуальному человеку, а с другой -  к людям, воспринимаемым как совокупность индивидуумов.

Интересно также обратить внимание на словарь:

У ОЖЕГОВА

ЧЕЛОВЕЧЕСКИЙ,  1.  см. человек.  2.  То  же,  что  человечный. Человеческое отношение. По-человечески (нареч.) поступил.
ЛЮДСКОЙ см. люди.

ЧЕЛОВЕЧНЫЙ,   Достойный  человека,  отзывчивый, гуманный.  Человечное  отношение.  Поступить  человечно  (нареч.).

Answer (score 1):

Никакой разницы нет, это полные синонимы, кроме последнего значения ЛЮДСКАЯ - субстантивированное прил. к "человек, люди"(историзм) в старой России  - прислуга в ресторане, трактире и т. п. ◆

СРАВНИМ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ: Человеческий -

1. Соотносящийся по знач. с сущ.: человек (живое существо из рода homo sapiens), связанный с ним.
2. Свойственный человеку (1), характерный для него. // перен. Достойный человека (2); человечный, гуманный.
3. Принадлежащий человеку (1).
4. Состоящий из людей.
5. Производимый, осуществляемый человеком (1).

Людской -
1) Соотносящийся по знач. с сущ.: люди (1*), связанный с ним.

2) Свойственный людям (1*), характерный для них.

3) Принадлежащий людям , состоящий из людей(1*).Людские пороки, людское море

4) Предназначенный для людей .Людская-прил. к "люди" в  знач. "прислуга"(историзм).

Answer (score 0):

Слова **"люд"**, **"люди"** имеют по-видимому более древнее, праиндоевропейское происхождение, потому что что-то похожее есть и в старо-английском и в древнегерманском (liudiz) и других языках.
Стар. англ. - lēod, lēode
Стар. сакс. - liud, liudi

Ссылка на англ. словарь, где подобрано много слов, похожих на **"люд"** и **"люди"**, в разных языках.
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Germanic/liudiz

Реконструкция праиндоевропейского корня: *leudʰ-

А слово **"человек"** характерно для славянских языков и латышского (предположительно, заимствование из древнеславянского).

Comment: Технический вопрос. (Или это в раздел Мета?)

Что-то не могу вставить эту ссылку по-нормальному. Т.е. чтобы нажать на русское слово в тексте и перейти на нужный адрес. Может в этой ссылке какие-то символы недопустимые?

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Germanic/liudiz

Answer (score 0):

Всё *человеческое* представляется на уровне личности. *Людское* было и является собирательным понятием о люде (или людях) как толпе и народе: мужик, простолюдин, слуга, мирянин, барин, воин и т.д. «Князья людские — князья народов». А из народов складывается человечество.